# How to add Microdata attributes in PHP

Tags: php, html, microdata

I use Microdata attributes in HTML code.

How can I add Microdata attributes to the following tag (PHP)?

```php
if (!empty($speciality)) {
echo "<p><strong>" . __('Speciality', 'framework') . "</strong><span>" . $speciality . "</span></p>";}
```

The page will not load when I enter the following way :

```php
echo "<p itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/medicalSpecialty"><strong>" . __('Speciality', 'framework') . "</strong><span itemprop="medicalSpecialty" >" . $speciality . "</span></p>";
```

Comment: Notice your mistake here: `"<p itemscope itemtype="https:..` you have two `"`, one should be escaped or `'` must be used. I also don't understand what this here should do: `__('Speciality', 'framework')`. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using double quotes in a double quotes which is wrong, use backslash or single quote when you need.
Try This code

```
echo "<p itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/medicalSpecialty'><strong>" . __('Speciality', 'framework') . "</strong><span itemprop='medicalSpecialty' >" . $speciality . "</span></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing single and double quotes but you need to reserve either single or double quotes to escape the string so that your PHP isn't read as HTML when echoed. The below snippet will work without any errors:

```
if (!empty($speciality)) {    
echo "<p itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/medicalSpecialty'><strong>'". 
__('Speciality', 'framework') . "'</strong><span itemprop='medicalSpecialty' 
>'" . $speciality . "'</span></p>";
}
```